# Angular7 child1 to parent - parent to child2 communication error

Tags: angular, observable

just an example for my issue:-
Parent have child1 and  child2.

I am showing a list of months in an array,  onLoad of child2.

on click of buttons at child1, months will be pop n push.

on click of a button on child1, its emitting new value to parent and further that value will go from parent to child2.ts and update the month's array

The issue is,  I am getting an error while communication from parent to child2. 
I used observable subscription method and it says

```
this.months.asObservable is not a function
```

Below is my code.

```js
////////////////child1.ts///////////////////////////////////

onClick() {
  this.navigateMonths.emit(this.month);
}



////////////// parent.ts//////////////////////
months: Subject < void > = new Subject < void > ();
navigatedMonths(months) {
  this.months = months;
  this.months.asObservable();
}

/////////child2.ts////////////////////////
@Input() navigatedMonths: Observable < void > ;
ngOnInit() {
  this.navigatedMonths.subscribe((months) => {
    this.months = months;
  })
  this.getMonths(this.year, this.month);

}
```

```html
////////////// parent.html//////////////////////////////////////////
< child2 class="row-items" [navigatedMonths]="months">< /child2>
< child1(navigateMonths)='navigatedMonths($event)'> Next Month< /child1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you have mentioned can be achieved by emitting data from `child1 to parent`  (using eventEmitters)

> child1.ts

```
  i = 0;
  months = ["jan","feb","march","april"];
  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  sendMessage() {
     this.messageEvent.emit(this.months[this.i]);
     this.i++;
  }
```

and then from `parent to child2` (using @viewChild).

> parent.ts

```
  message:string;
  @ViewChild(Child2Component) child;
  receiveMessage($event) {
     this.message = $event
     this.child.addMonth(this.message);
  }
```

> child2.ts

```
  months:any[] = [];
  @Input() childMessage: string;
  addMonth(month){
     this.months.push(month);
     console.log(this.months);
  }
```

working demo added:[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-ypcupj)

**Note**: output of child2's months array can be seen at console.

**Edit:** Following is the second method using `Subject` in `service`. This method can be used for all types of component interactions. Whether it be `parent-child` or `child-parent` or `siblings` interactions.

You should follow following steps:

> myService.ts

Create a subject in service. (Subject need to be imported from rxjs)

```
mySubject = new Subject();
```

> child1.ts

Add/push item to Subject using `next()`:

```
this.myService.mySubject.next(this.months[this.i++])
```

> child2.ts

Subscribe to Subject to read the item:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.myService.mySubject.subscribe((data)=>{
     this.months.push(data);
     console.log(this.months);
   });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it? Its interesting but not able to understand hows it working for parent to child2

Comment: @developer  ViewChild allows a one component to be injected into another, giving the parent access to its attributes and functions. So with child2 reference in parent i'm calling its addMonth() function to add months to child2's array.

Comment: Can we do it using subscription way? Senior developer said basically you're doing parentcomponent.childComponent.childFunction() which is not right approach

Comment: you should really read this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction :) This page also shows Himanshu Singh solution as possibility. But as mentioned in my answer I would rather go for the service solution (where the service holds a subject of months and whatever component is interested in it can subscribe on it). Your senior will be happy ;)

Answer (score 1):

quickfix - get rid of the observables/subjects which are not needed

```
////////////// parent.ts//////////////////////
months: any[]; // no subject anymore
navigatedMonths(months) {
  this.months = months;
}

/////////child2.ts////////////////////////
@Input() 
set navigatedMonths(months: any[]) { // make a setter from your input
   // Do whatever you want when new months come in
}
```

You should probably consider to introduce a service which is shared between the two childs. The parent does not have to know about the months.

Read this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction (*Parent and children communicate via a service*) - same applies for communication between to components (even if they have no parent - child relation ship)

The service could look like this:

```
export class MonthsService {

  // private for internal use
  private monthsSource: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]); // init with empty array

  // public for use in components or other services
  months$: Observable<string[]> = this.monthsSource.asObservable(); 

  addMonth(newMonth: string) {
    const months = [...this.monthsSource.getValue(), newMonth]; // Create new months array
    this.monthsSource.next(months);
  }
}
```

Complete example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-ddozvn

Now the childs have no inputs or outputs anymore, the parent component stays clean. Every component which is interested in the data simply subscribes to the months$ observable.

Comment: How I should fix it? I am confused now

Comment: navigatedMonths(months){
      this.months = months;
      this.months.asObservable();  /////// this is an error
    }

Comment: Ahhh I see. this.months is not an observable/subject at that point. .asObservable works only on Subjects

Comment: I just added the solution to my answer which uses a service for holding the months data

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use 2-way binding with `@Input()`, `@Output()` and `EventEmitter`.  By naming your `@Output()` `EventEmitter` the same name as you `@Input()` and append `Change` to the name, you can achieve 2-way binding.

#### child1.component.ts

```
@Input()
public message: Message;

@Output()
public messageChange: EventEmitter<Message> = new EventEmitter<Message>();

public text: string;

send() {
  if (this.text.trim().length > 0) {
    this.messageChange.emit(new Message(`Child1: ${this.text}`));
  }
}
```

#### parent.component.html

```
<app-child1 [(message)]="message"></app-child1>
<app-child2 [(message)]="message"></app-child2>
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-46ndlt
>
> https://medium.com/@preethi.s/angular-custom-two-way-data-binding-3e618309d6c7